# Extract from a NODE-RED string

Tags: javascript, web-services, node-red

I have my NODE-RED schemma:

[image]

following string result from my "Function" node my node:

```
msg.payload : string[63]
"{"random":{"date":"22:55","random":21},"time":{"time":"22:52"}}"
```

This is the code of my "Function Node":

```
msg.payload.random=context.global.randomandtime;
msg.payload.time=context.global.time;

return msg;
```

I need to put in  "part of the string" (not all) like this =>{"date":"**22:55**","random":**21**} and show it in my browser like a webpage but not using html tags.

Like this:

**22:55**

**21**

Any help will be wellcome.

---

I have added template(Mustache) and I am traying to bring data to it,(Note:http response is already in schemme but not shown here)

[image]

I am traying to bring data here (template). But I get error.

The Mustache template body is:

This is the payload: {{#payload.randomandandtime.random}} !

But I have back this error back:

2017-5-18 16:18:00node: Mustachemsg : string[56]

"Unclosed section "payload.randomandandtime.random" at 59"

In browser I get

502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.

Even If I change it only payload.randomandandtime I get empty:

payload.randomandandtime

In browser & console:

Messsage received back: (empty)
This is the payload: !

Comment: What have you already tried and have you looked at the template node?

Comment: Hi hardillb. Please check it, I have added extra informaation at the end of my request here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved in this way.
I make all in one Global varaible instead 2 global variables.
I passed it to mustache template and in Mustache I worked with context in order to get it.

General Scheme:
[image]

Then in recoverydata:

```
msg.payload = context.global.get("randomtime");
```

In My Mustache:

```
`{{#payload.random}}
Last random number request returned {{&payload.random}}, which was received 
at {{&payload.randomtime.times}}{{/payload.random}}
{{/payload}}`
```

The resul of it is a Webservice not using HTML and this is:

url https://....../page

***"Time last server time request received at 13:14 Last random number request returned 94, which was received at 13:14"***